# Show div tag after scrolling 100px from in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working filename.vue file. I am trying to add a div to show up after scroll 100px. I am not able to get it. Please help me find out where I am going wrong.

```
<template>
 <div id="sectionTop"> 
  <div id="scrollButton"> 
   <a class="topButton" href="javascript:document.getElementById('sectionTop').scrollIntoView(true);"><img src="../../images/uparrow.svg"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 $(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 800) {
      $('.scrollButton').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.scrollButton').fadeOut();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Updated as per suggested

```
<template>
 <div id="sectionTop"> 
  <div id="scrollButton"> 
   <a class="topButton" href="javascript:document.getElementById('sectionTop').scrollIntoView(true);" v-if="scrollpx > 800"><img src="../../images/uparrow.svg"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {    
    data() {
      return {
        scrollpx: 0
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleScroll() {
        this.scrollpx = window.scrollY;
      }
    },
    created() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    },
    destroyed() {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this problem.

```
<a class="scrollTop" href="javascript:document.getElementById('sectionTop').scrollIntoView(true);" title='Click here to go to the top' v-if="scrollpx > 100"><img src="../../images/uparrow.svg"></a>

<script>
  export default {    
    data() {
      return {
        scrollpx: 0
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleScroll() {
        this.scrollpx = document.body.scrollTop;
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      document.body.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    } 
  };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery to do this. You can register an event listener for scroll events in the `created` method of your vue component (don't forget to unregister it afterwards!). In you `handleScroll` method you can then update a variable holding the current scrollY-value. Now this value is available to vue and can be used "reactively". For example, you can show your button using `v-if`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="replace"></div>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#replace',
    template: `
<div id="scroller">
 <div id="sectionTop" style="height: 5000px"> 
  Please Scroll down
  <div id="scrollButton"> 
   <a class="topButton" style="position:fixed" v-if="scrollpx > 800">Scroll top</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>`,
    data() {
      return {
        scrollpx: 0
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleScroll() {
        this.scrollpx = window.scrollY;
      }
    },
    created() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    },
    destroyed() {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Please have a look at my updated part. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: the issue is scrollpx is not updating

Comment: Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: The main difference is that adding the listener to `window` _should_ work with pages where you have a very large body-element while adding it to `document.body` should work with pages where the size of the body element is fixed and its content is larger.